# compare comma separated value with column collection of a table

Tags: sql-server

One table `X` is having a column `C1` and having value with comma separated, i.e., 1,2,3

Another table `Y` is having a column `C2` with unique `tinyint` value and having multiple rows and the column `C2` values are, i.e.,

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Requirement: Check is all the values of `X(C1)` are exist in the `Y(C2)` table
Tried One:

```
((select Data from dbo.split(X.C1,',')) in  ((Select C2 from Y where <some condition>)))
```

Where Split is a user defined function which splits based on 'Comma' and put it into individual rows of a table and returns that table, i.e.,
`Split(X.C1,',')` returns a table with multiple rows like

```
1
2
3
```

But, using this query is giving run time error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Could any one please help to get more feasible solution

Thanks in Advance
Kiran Bussa

Comment: Post your complete query. In your given query there is not operator from exception.

Comment: Ideally, change the design. SQL has a data type *designed* for holding multiple values and lots of support for working with those values - it's called a table. Stuffing multiple values into a string and then struggling to work with them as separate values isn't caused by a limitation of SQL - it's caused by using the wrong data type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to join the two parts of your query.

i.e.

```
((SELECT Data from dbo.split(X.C1,',') WHERE data.C1 IN ((Select C2 from Y WHERE <some condition>)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the unwanted brackets and add `where` condition

```
SELECT Data
FROM   dbo.Split(X.C1, ',')
WHERE  data IN (SELECT C2
                FROM   Y
                WHERE <SOME condition>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to split the comma separated values and store in a table variable. This will help you to query with your records.

For your reference i have create a small sqlfiddle using CROSS Apply to split the comma separated values and check in Y table.

[CLICK HERE FOR FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ceebc/15)

You can also refer to the complete code as below:

```
Create table x (c1 varchar(10) )

insert into x values ('1,2,3')
insert into x values ('1,2,4')
insert into x values ('2,3,4')
insert into x values ('1,2')

create table Y (c1 tinyint) 
insert into Y values (1)
insert into Y values (2)
insert into Y values (3)
insert into Y values (4)
insert into Y values (5)


SELECT DISTINCT Data.C1
FROM   
(select 
  n.r.value('.', 'varchar(50)') AS C1
from x as T
  cross apply (select cast('<r>'+replace(replace(c1,'&','&amp;'), ',', '</r><r>')+'</r>' as xml)) as S(XMLCol)
  cross apply S.XMLCol.nodes('r') as n(r))  DATA
WHERE  data.C1 IN (SELECT C1
                FROM   Y)
```

**EDIT: based on the comment Edited the answer with Where condition**

Please refer to the new fiddle link below 
EDITED FIDDLE [CLICK HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ceebc/19)

For same table structure new select query to identify the column in which the value appeared.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Data.C1, DATA.FROMX
FROM   
(select 
 T.C1 as FROMX, 
  n.r.value('.', 'varchar(50)') AS C1
from x as T
  cross apply (select cast('<r>'+replace(replace(c1,'&','&amp;'), ',', '</r><r>')+'</r>' as xml)) as S(XMLCol)
  cross apply S.XMLCol.nodes('r') as n(r))  DATA
WHERE  data.C1 IN (SELECT C1
                FROM   Y WHERE Y.C1 = 4)
```

Comment: The specified condition , SELECT Data
FROM   dbo.Split(X.C1, ',')
WHERE  data IN (SELECT C2
                FROM   Y
                WHERE <SOME condition>) is using in a stored procedure to get boolean value (True/False), for further values to select from other tables, the given solution to get the table resultant, which even we are getting through 'Split' method.  Any other solutions, please

Comment: You can add your condition in your query like `WHERE Y.C1  = 2`

Comment: X.C1= 1,2,3 and Y.C1(rows) = 1 2 3 4 5 6, in this scenario 1,2,3 of X.C1 are exist in Y.C1(rows), and the condition should return appropriate boolean which is not happening

Comment: Please check the updated link and let me know if you  are facing any concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Hurray!!!! Finally got the solution :)

declare @Int_Res varchar(max)
set @Int_Res = ''
SELECT @Int_Res = @Int_Res + ',' + Cast(C1 as varchar) FROM X where

dbo.Split((@Int_Res ),',') Int_Result

(Int_Result.Data in (Select C1 from Y where ))